# How to get the current classes of an element in an Angular directive

Tags: angular, class, directive

I have to make an Angular 7 directive where I can toggle (add/remove) a class from the element (ElementRef). When the class in not in the element add it, and when it's in the element remove it.

I know how to add / remove a class ... but how to get the current classes of an element ? ... so I can check if I have to add or remove

Answer (score 4):

To get the current classes of an element, you could do:

```js
    const elementRef: ElementRef; // assuming your inject it in your constructor 

    const classes = elementRef.nativeElement.classList;
    if (classes.contains('your class')
    {
       // do something
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can inject an `ElementRef` in the directive constructor and and access the classes of the element on which directive is applied using

```
this._el.nativeElement.getAttribute('class')
```

Where `this._el` is the injected `ElementRef`.

See an example here:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bo6xtg