# How to check if child element has class?

Tags: angular

I use ElementRef in Angular to get DOM elements:

```
private el: ElementRef;

this.el.nativeElement.children[0];
```

How to check if element `this.el.nativeElement.children[0]` has specific class?

Comment: Check the answer by Thierno Bary: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55851815/how-to-get-the-current-classes-of-an-element-in-an-angular-directive/55851992#55851992

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the current classes of an element in an Angular directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55851815/how-to-get-the-current-classes-of-an-element-in-an-angular-directive)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is a specific class and you know it, you can use *instanceof*. Like:

```
console.log(this.el.nativeElement.children[0] instanceof ClassName);
```

And it will print true or false, based on the result.